# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. Please help me insert syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my command

```
db.tasks.insert({id : “0”, title : "task01”, description : "description", status : "1", assignorId : "7", assigneeId : “8", createdDate : “", startedDate : “", targetDate : “", completeDate : “", closedDate : “"})
```

MongoDB told my the syntax has an error.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're using curly quotes. Only plain quotes work:

```
db.tasks.insert({id : "0", title : "task01", description : "description", status : "1", assignorId : "7", assigneeId : "8", createdDate : "", startedDate : "", targetDate : "", completeDate : "", closedDate : ""})
```

Comment: Thanks. I copied and pasted from my Evernote, and had this problem-drove me nuts.

Comment: evernote did the same thing to me! +1 on the answer

Comment: Notes on my Mac causing the same issue!

Comment: I don't even know how to type straight quotes on my mac. I had to run find and replace in Notes to fix that. Slightly irritating lol +1 from me

Comment: @AaronPennington Maybe you should use a text editor for coding instead.

Comment: I was using webStorm but accessing the mongo console in the embedded terminal and all I was getting was curly quotes aka unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: absolutely wasted 1 hour to find it being this curly quotes issues.  Thanks for your answer, saved me further time... !